# Extract number from column to make a new column in Pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have a column named Rate like below. All I want to do is to create a new column Rate_New that only extract the number part from Rate, which is 0.25. How to do that? Thanks!!

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame({'Rate':['$0.25/Wh', '$0.25/Wh', '$0.25/Wh', '$0.25/Wh']})
df
```

Comment: You should tag this with `regex`, I think that is the meat and potatoes of your problem

Comment: @Matt Thanks, I just added the tag.

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?
What doesn't work with your code and where is it?

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my solution, you can copy and paste to use it:

```
df['Rate_New'] = df.Rate.apply(lambda x: float(x.replace("$","").replace("/Wh","")))
```

Or this, no apply, no attribute:

```
df["Rate"].str.replace("$","").str.replace("/Wh","")
```

Here is the version using regex, no attribute-style no apply.

```
repl = lambda m: m.group(1)
df["Rate"].str.replace(r'\$(.+?)\/Wh', repl, regex=True)
```

Comment: Why use the attribute-style column access? More importantly, why are you using `apply()` and a lambda for this?

Comment: Please see my revised version.

Comment: Are you opposed to using regex?

Comment: No objection, please see my revised version, I thought you said not to use lambda? Do you have an idea to use regex without lambda? BTW, just out of curiousity I found some reply in this question used exactly same solution, why I was downvoted, but they are not?

Comment: @sun I agree. Someone's obviously ruining everyone's learning and sharing opportunities here, which is such a bummer on stackoverflow.

Comment: H  FiFiFiona, thank you for your support, I updated my answer as well. Your vote make me feel there are more good in SO!

Answer (score 2):

```
df["Rate_New"] = df.Rate.str.split(r"[$/]").apply(lambda x: x[1]).astype(float)
```

- The `.str.split()` method converts original values into lists:

  > ```
  > 0    [, 0.25, Wh]
  > 1    [, 0.25, Wh]
  > 2    [, 0.25, Wh]
  > 3    [, 0.25, Wh]
  > Name: Rate, dtype: object
  > ```
- The lambda function extracts middle elements (i.e. with index `1`) from these lists:

  > ```
  > 0    0.25
  > 1    0.25
  > 2    0.25
  > 3    0.25
  > Name: Rate, dtype: object
  > ```
- The `.astype()` method then changes the data type to `float`:

  > ```
  > 0    0.25
  > 1    0.25
  > 2    0.25
  > 3    0.25
  > Name: Rate, dtype: float64
  > ```
- `df["Rate_New"] =` then assigns such created series as a new column to your dataframe:

  > ```
  >        Rate  Rate_New
  > 0  $0.25/Wh      0.25
  > 1  $0.25/Wh      0.25
  > 2  $0.25/Wh      0.25
  > 3  $0.25/Wh      0.25
  > ```

Comment: Why complicate things so much? Also, why do you use the attribute/`.` style for column access?

Comment: **1.** Where's yours, less complicated solution? **2.** Read the docs. @AMC

Answer (score 0):

First add a method that extracts number from 
Rate, say `extract_rate()`

```
def extract_rate(rate):
    return rate.replace('$', '').replace('/Wh', '')
```

Then, you can apply the method to the entire column to generate a new column.

```
df['Rate_new'] = df.apply(lambda row: extract_rate(row['Rate']), axis = 1)t_rate(row['Rate']), axis = 1)
```

Comment: Why use `apply()`, a function, and a lambda instead of the string manipulation methods provided by Pandas?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace them as following:

```
df["Rate_new"] = df["Rate"].apply(lambda x: x.replace("$", "").replace("/Wh", ""))
```

Comment: Why use `apply()` and a lambda instead of the string manipulation methods provided by Pandas?

Answer (score 0):

```
df["Rate_New"] = df.Rate.str.replace(r"\$(.+)/Wh", lambda m: m.group(1)).astype(float)
```

- The regular expression has 1 capturing group — all symbols between `$` and `/Wh`.
- The lambda function replaces the original string with this capturing group.
- The `.astype()` method then changes the data type (from "object") to `float`.

Answer (score -1):

This can be achieved with the following code which you can place in separate Jupyter cells:

```py
    # Import the Pandas and regex libraries 
    import pandas as pd
    import re

    # Use your dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Rate':['$0.25/Wh', '$0.25/Wh', '$0.25/Wh', '$0.25/Wh']})

    # State regex pattern that extracts the value
    pattern = r"(?:[]{1}[,\d]+.?\d*)"

    # Iterate over rate column of dataframe and perform regex to extract value
    search = []    
    for values in df['Rate']:
        search.append(re.search(pattern, values).group())

    df['Rate_New'] = search

   # Display the result of the dataframe with appended column
    df
```

Comment: Why use something so complex, though?

Comment: loops in pandas are a bad idea.